# Can't connect to an Azure-based SQL Server VM from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure-virtual-machine

I created an Azure SQL VM using the instructions below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/create-sql-vm-portal?view=azuresql

I used mixed mode authentication and created a SQL login that has sysadmin privileges. I also used the public access with external IP option.

I can RDP into the VM and use SSMS on the server itself to access SQL Server. However, when I try to come at the server from outside, authentication fails. It finds the server, but using the sysadmin login credentials that I just created won't get me in.

The firewall rules, TCP pipe, and all the other common things seem to be squared away. The Microsoft website above seems to indicate that it should... just work. But it doesn't. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you login with the *sql login* from local server & ssms? usually ssms defaults to windows auth

Comment: No, I get the same error when attempting to connect that way from the local server as I do when attempting to connect from outside:
Login failed for user 'xxxx'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

The only way I can connect to the server using SSMS is when connected via RDP and using the default (as you noted) windows authentication.

Comment: Check the SQL Server logs and get the true authentication error. If you don't understand that error, [edit] it into your question.

Comment: Ugh, that got it. The error was "An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only". I thought I read that when setting up the VM it would allow for SQL authentication, but apparently I was wrong. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Please feel free to repost your comment as a solution so I can upvote it.

Comment: `I used mixed mode authentication` - what does this means in the context of the error you got

Comment: I thought that I had enabled SQL Server authentication as a part of creating the VM, but apparently that didn't happen. So I just had to enable it in the server and my problem was resovled.